# I want to redirect to a new page after submitting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a shopping cart page . Where i want to get information about my customter.i have a submit button

```
<input type="button" id="submit-cart" value='Submit' onclick="submit_cart()" />
```

I want to get redirected to a new page after the submission of the form onclick.

Comment: Have you spent time researching/searching this? There are many ways to do this.

Comment: Chris Coyier just posted this the other day: http://css-tricks.com/redirect-web-page/

Comment: Do this in the same place that you handle the form submit, whether that's server-side, JS, w/e. After you've processed the form, you can use your JS, PHP, w/e to redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `window.location = url` to redirect

So this would look like

```
function submit_cart() {
    var url = 'xyz.com' // Some url you want to redirect to
    window.location = url;
}
```

In php you can do this by using `header` function:

```
<?php
  header('Location: xyz.com'); // xyz.com is the url you want to redirect to
  exit();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function submit_cart () {

/* do something amazing you always wanted to do with the user's data */
window.location.assign('/* here comes the url the user should be sent to */');
}
```

Or, without javascript at all:

```
<form action = "url to redirect to" method="<!-- POST / GET -->">
  <input type="text" name="textinput"/>
  <input type="submit" class="button" id="submit-cart" value='Submit'/>
</form>
```